# Do firebase cloud functions "die" after 30 days?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I was at a Firebase Cloud Functions talk hosted by my local Google Developer Group. Here, some people talked about cloud functions "dying" (maybe needing redeployment?) after 30 days. However, I can't find any information on the subject in the firebase docs or anywhere else online.

I hope somebody knows something about this!